# Problems with Bootstrap Dual List Box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

**What I have now:** I show the contents of a `JSON` in the options within a selection, which with the help of the plugin [bootstrap-duallistbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) shows it in the form of a dual list With which Certain selected options can be added or deleted.

**My problem:** What fails is that when selecting an option and pass it to the next area pull all and not just one, I do not know what to expect, I hope they can help me, I leave the advance I take [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/63ZRPOIiTr64yILOzUY7?p=preview)

Comment: Your code in plunkr does not work. It only displays a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `Jquery` dual list box you could use the directive for `angularJs` in here https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-duallistbox download the zip and install it with `bower` if you not fan with `bower` you could change the paths of the `script` and `css` files in this code below :

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>AngularJS Bootstrap Duallistbox example</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap-duallistbox/src/bootstrap-duallistbox.css">
 </head>
 <body ng-app="bsDuallistboxApp">

 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select
          ng-model="model"
          ng-options="obj as obj.text for obj in list track by obj.id"
          multiple
          bs-duallistbox
          bootstrap2="{{ settings.bootstrap2 }}"

          move-on-select="{{ settings.moveOnSelect }}"
          preserve-selection="{{ settings.preserveSelection }}"

          move-selected-label="{{ settings.moveSelectedLabel }}"
          move-all-label="{{ settings.moveAllLabel }}"
          remove-selected-label="{{ settings.removeSelectedLabel }}"
          remove-all-label="{{ settings.removeAllLabel }}"

          non-selected-list-label="{{ settings.nonSelectedListLabel }}"
          selected-list-label="{{ settings.selectedListLabel }}"

          postfix="{{ settings.postfix }}"
          select-min-height="{{ settings.selectMinHeight }}"

          filter="{{ settings.filter }}"
          filter-values="{{ settings.filterValues }}"
          filter-non-selected="settings.filterNonSelected"
          filter-selected="settings.filterSelected"
          filter-placeholder="{{ settings.filterPlaceholder }}"
          filter-clear="{{ settings.filterClear }}"
          info-all="{{ settings.infoAll }}"
          info-filtered="{{ settings.infoFiltered }}"
          info-empty="{{ settings.infoEmpty }}"

  </select>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-large" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="../angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="../bootstrap-duallistbox/src/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js">   </script>
 <script src="../common/module.js"></script>
 <script src="../bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="../src/directives/bsDuallistbox.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

all files are included in zip file you have to just redefine the path.